# Difference Between "langer" and "länger"

Tags: adjective, comparative

What's the difference between "langer" and "länger"? Google Translate returns "longer" for both?

Comment: Google Translate has corrected *langer* to *länger* for you. It will probably be different if you enter a correct sentence with *langer*.

Answer (score 8):

We are talking about the adjective [*lang*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lang) here.

Notice that the initial letter of german adjectives is usually lowercase, though there are [exceptions](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Rechtschreibung/Gro%C3%9F-_und_Kleinschreibung_von_Adjektiven), which I won't go into now.

The form *langer* is simply a form of strong [declension of *lang*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:lang#lang_(Deklination)_(Deutsch)). It occurs in the following situations:

> - nominative singular for masculine genus
>     
>     „Es war ein *langer* Tag.“
>     
>     <sup>("It was a *long* day.")</sup>
> - genitive singular for feminine genus
>     
>     „*Langer* Rede kurzer Sinn ...“
>     
>     <sup>("To make a *long* story short ...")</sup>
> - dative singular for feminine genus
>     
>     „Sie lief stets mit *langer* Hose herum.“
>     
>     <sup>("She always walked around with *long* trousers.")</sup>
> - genitive plural  for all genera
>     
>     „Ich bin kein Freund *langer* Abende.“
>     
>     <sup>("I am not a friend of *long* evenings.")</sup>

The form *länger* is the predicatively used [comparative of *lang*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:lang#Komparativ).

> „Deine Haare sind *länger* als meine.“
>   
>   <sup>("Your hair is *longer* than mine.")</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Google translate is inferior to a decent dictionary, and there are many ones online which would have answered this question (which is therefore likely to be closed).

*Langer* is the masculine adjective, as in *langer Tag* (long day). *Länger* is the comparative as in

> Das dauert noch länger. (This will take longer).

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to Björn Friedrich's answer, two possibilities where "Langer" would be written with a capital "l" like you wrote originally:
If there is a friend of yours who is significantly taller than you, you might greet him with

> "Wie geht's, Langer?"
>   ("what's up, long (=tall) one?")

And also "Langer" is a German family name, e.g. of former professional golf player Bernhard Langer